# How to change the size of a european resistor in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

This is my very first question i'm going to ask here. Allready found very helpfull tips, so i hope you can help me.

I'm drawing a circuit with circuitikz. In there i only want to change the **size of the resistor, but not of the other components**. Therefore i used the commands `\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}` and `\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}`. This worked fine with american resistors but i'd like to use the european ones. Is there a simillar command for achieving this?

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

% original size
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[R] (2,0) to[Do] (4,0);
    \ctikzset{resistor = european}
    \draw (6,0) to[R] (8,0) to[Do] (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

% shrink resistor
\ctikzset{resistor = american}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[R] (2,0) to[Do] (4,0);
    \ctikzset{resistor = european}
    \draw (6,0) to[R] (8,0) to[Do] (10,0); % this one is NOT smaller 
    % than the one above, but I WANT IT TO BE SMALLER
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the new `resistors/scale=` command in circuitikz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me as this is not possible in this way. `bipoles/resistor/height` and `width` has been hardcoded for the American variants. The only possibility I am seeing here is to change the length of the bipole. The length is a possible parameter of each bipole.

This could look like in my MWE below:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}    
    % original size
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[R] (2,0) to[Do] (4,0);
    \ctikzset{resistor = european}
    \draw (6,0) to[R] (8,0) to[Do] (10,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % shrink resistor
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[R] (2,0) to[Do] (4,0);
    \ctikzset{resistor = european}
    \draw (6,0) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=20pt, R] (8,0) to[Do] (10,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. With a `\tikzset{rLength/.style={/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=20pt}}` i could shorten the `to` option measurably, cause i've got many resistors in my circuit.