# Is it possible to make all resistors red (or all capacitors blue, etc) in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circuitikz

Is it possible to make `circuitikz` draw all resistors red or all capacitors blue? I can make all bipoles thick, for example, but cant make all resistors red. I have to write the color explicitly. I cannot find a `ctikzset` command for this. 
This is an example. I want to get rid of the `color=red` for all resistors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,circuits,calc,babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=1.0,thick]
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
\ctikzset{label/align = smart}
\draw (0, 0) to [battery1, color=green, l=$\mathcal{E}$, invert] (0, 4) -- (4,4) to [R, l^=$R_1$, color=red] (2,2) to [R=$R_2$, color=red] (4, 0) -- (0, 0);
\draw (4, 4) to [R=$R_4$, color=red] (6, 2) to [R = $R_3$, color=red] (4, 0);
\draw (2, 2) to [C = $C$, color=blue] (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit: Making the code compilable.

Comment: If you complete your code so that it is compileable without further manual changes, then it will be easier to help. Right now it's not compileable.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194696/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-european-resistor-in-circuitikz

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, you can set the height and width using those flags, but not the color. I have not found yet how to do that and after checking the circuitikz code (I am not a Latex expert so I could have missed it) I cannot find any clue on how to set the color, not the dimensions. That is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\tikzset{R/.append style={color=red}}` (see [`pgfkeys` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 888):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,circuits,calc,babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    R/.append style={color=red},
    C/.append style={color=blue},
    battery1/.append style={color=green},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=1.0,thick]
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}
\ctikzset{label/align = smart}
\draw (0, 0) to [battery1, l=$\mathcal{E}$] (0, 4) -- (4,4) to [R, l^=$R_1$] (2,2) to [R=$R_2$] (4, 0) -- (0, 0);
\draw (4, 4) to [R=$R_4$] (6, 2) to [R = $R_3$] (4, 0);
\draw (2, 2) to [C = $C$] (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

**Edit:** If you want to change the color of the labels, too, you can use the `/tikz/text` key:

```
\tikzset{
    R/.append style={color=red, /tikz/text=red},
    C/.append style={color=blue, /tikz/text=blue},
    battery1/.append style={color=green, /tikz/text=green},
}
```

[image: screenshot of the edit]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I have to fiz those labels :)

Comment: That is useful. Although I mean the positions. Thanks again.

Comment: @iluvatar have you figured out how that works? According to the [circuitikz documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) (page 34) it should be possible to specify whether the label shall be placed above or below with `l^=$R_1$` or `l_=$R_1$`. However that does not seem to work on my system (version 0.3.0).

Comment: Hi @jakun, yes, that does not work either for me, and I am not sure if it is due to the fact that the labels are rotated ... At the end I leave them as shown.